# Iterating through IList<>

Tags: c#, list, loops

Here's a scenario that is playing out for an for each loop that I'm doing;

Basically I want to remove a record from lstMaster if there is a match in lstChild but the results I'm getting back are inconclusive - I should be removing 800 or so records but I'm only removing 256 or so records.

The outer loop is lstMaster has 1600 records.
The inner loop is lstChild has 800 which are not suposed to exist in lstMaster.

So if a match is fouond in lstChild then the record is removed in lstMaster.

Am I missing something in the loop?

```
for(int i=lstMaster.Count-1; i > 0; i--)
   {
   for(int j=lstChildcare.Count-1; j > 0; j--)
      {
        if( lstChildcare[j].school_license == lstMaster[i].school_license )
        {
            textboxStatus.AppendText(Text = "Removing duplicate row: " + i                 + " School: " + lstMaster[i].school_name + Environment.NewLine); 
                    lstMaster.RemoveAt(i);
                    counter++;

                }

          }

      }
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is C#?

Comment: Could you identify which records should be removed but aren't?

Comment: Hi - yes, this is in c#. Yes - I could identify records that should be moving out and they aren't being moved out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looping in reverse (starting from the last item and ending in the first item), then you should be fine.

The only problem I see is removing an item from `lstMaster` and then trying to access the same index again in the next loop over `lstChildcare`.

To fix this, simply break the inner loop once you decide to remove the item from the `lstMaster` list. Since you removed the item, there is no need to continue the loop.

Reaplce this:

```
lstMaster.RemoveAt(i);
counter++;
```

Add this:

```
lstMaster.RemoveAt(i);
counter++;
break;
```

If for some reason, you need to detect all matches between the parent and child lists, you can simply delete the item form the parent list after you loop through the child list like this:

```
for (int i = lstMaster.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    bool delete = false;

    for (int j = lstChildcare.Count - 1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        if (lstChildcare[j].school_license == lstMaster[i].school_license)
        {
            textboxStatus.AppendText(MediaTypeNames.Text = "Removing duplicate row: " + i + " School: " + lstMaster[i].school_name + Environment.NewLine);
            delete = true;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    if(delete)
        lstMaster.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your lists are actually the concrete type `List<T>` for you master and child list you can remove unwanted items with a `Predicate(T)` match in the `RemoveAll` method. You can also make your ChildCare object inherit from `IEquatable<T>` to control how it's considered equal and do something similar to below. I made stuff up since I don't know what's in your actual class other than a license BUT you can get the idea from this example. You can copy and paste it straight into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and run it to give it a try.

```
void Main()
{
    var masterChildcare = new List<ChildCare>
    {
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "One"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Two"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Three"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Four"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Five"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Six"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Seven"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Eight"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Nine"},
     new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Ten"},
    };
    var childChildcare = new List<ChildCare>
    {
        new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Three"},
        new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Eight"},
        new ChildCare{SchoolLicense= "Nine"}
    };
    masterChildcare.Dump();

    masterChildcare.RemoveAll(childCare => childChildcare.Contains(childCare));
    masterChildcare.Dump();

}

public class ChildCare : IEquatable<ChildCare>
{
    public string SchoolLicense { get; set;}

    public bool Equals(ChildCare other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (SchoolLicense == other.SchoolLicense)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        ChildCare other = obj as ChildCare;
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return SchoolLicense.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Never remove items from a list directly within a loop.

The size of the list changes!

So the for loop that iterates through the list doesn't actually see every item.

For example, if you remove item 2, then `i` gets incremented to `3` for the next item. But the old item 3 has now become 2. So this item never gets checked.

Instead, create a new list `items_to_be_deleted`, while in the loop, adding which items need to be deleted.

Then afterwards, delete those items.

Comment: That makes sense. After I create a list of items_to_be_deleted do I create another loop? Since I want to remove items from lstMaster so I loop through lsMaster.RemoveAt(items_to_be_deleted)...?

Comment: You could try `list2.Except(list1).ToList();`. Another thing to look into is the `removeAll` method, that takes a predicate.

Comment: This makes sense... But OP loops in reverse so it isnt really applicable